# Linux multicast source address

Tags: linux, networking, multicast

I have a linux system  (kernel 3.10.62 - yeah, I know it's old) with multiple interfaces:

- eth0 - 192.168.1.110/24
- eth1 - 10.149.1.4/24
- eth2 - 10.10.0.99/16

I'm trying to send to a multicast address (235.0.0.37) on the eth2 interface, with a source IP address of that eth2 interface.

I have the route table setup like:

```
# ip route
default via 10.10.0.99 dev eth2  scope link
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.110
10.149.1.0/24   dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.149.1.4
10.10.0.0/16    dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.0.99
224.0.0.0/4  dev eth0 scope link
235.0.0.0/24 dev eth2  scope link
```

I have a test python (2.7.3) app (real app is in Java, but this shows the problem cleanly, and the Java app behaves the same way):

```
# cat test_mc.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import struct

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.bind( ( "10.10.0.99", 0 ) )
print "bound to:", sock.getsockname()

sock.setsockopt( socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton("10.10.0.99") )

ifip = sock.getsockopt( socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF )
print socket.inet_ntoa( struct.pack('<L', ifip) )

sock.sendto(b'hello world', ('235.0.0.37', 9006))


# python test_mc.py
bound to: ('10.10.0.99', 49908)
10.10.0.99
#
```

Note that this binds the socket to the eth2 address as well as explicitly sets IP_MULTICAST_IF.

I'm expecting this message to go out the eth2 interface (10.10.0.99).  And it does do that, but the SOURCE ADDRESS of the packets is the eth1 interface (10.149.1.4).  I've confirmed this both with tcpdump on the localhost and wireshark on an external PC (connected to the eth2 network).

```
# tcpdump -X -n -i eth2 udp port 9006
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
17:58:10.915720 IP 10.149.1.4.49908 > 235.0.0.37.9006: UDP, length 11
        0x0000:  4500 0027 aa66 4000 0111 d8a1 0a95 0104  E..'.f@.........
        0x0010:  eb00 0025 c2f4 232e 0013 f6e2 6865 6c6c  ...%..#.....hell
        0x0020:  6f20 776f 726c 64                        o.world
```

Is there no way to setup the socket so that packets to that multicast address appear to be coming from the eth2 IP (10.10.0.99)?  I thought that the IP_MULTICAST_IF would have done that.  It's not even choosing the source address of the default multicast route (eth0), or the default route.  Is there no way to do this?

Comment: Couldn’t you just _bind_ to the _eth2_ address before sending?

Comment: I did try and bind to the eth2 address, it didn't make any difference.  I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: I'm not sure why, out of all the choices, the kernel would be choosing `10.149.1.4`, but I suspect, after reading [this](http://linux-ip.net/gl/ip-cref/ip-cref-node174.html), that it has something to do with one of (1) other addresses on the interfaces that haven't been mentioned, or (2) potentially having the sysctl `ip_dynaddr` setting active, or (3) the python script not using the low-level libraries correctly (I honestly don't know). Could you try setting the `src` parameter of the `235.0.0.0/24` route to `10.10.0.99`, like you have it for `10.10.0.0/16` route?